# Saving p-table columns sizes with onColResize and reverting to saved state

Tags: angular, primeng, p-table

What I am trying to do is to save a columns layout on p-table component of PrimeNG. I want to trigger saving method on `onColResize` event each time user will change a width of the column. Body of the event has two properties:

```
{
 "delta": number,
 "element": html_elem
}
```

It doesn't seems helpfull. So the question is - Is there any other way of getting table state and saving it eg. as an array of the objects like:

```
{
  "elem_id": "",
  "size": ""
}
```

I went through a lot of stackoverflow questions and documentation but I didn't found a solution to my problem. Kindly as for help.